# Use ToDictionary to create a dictionary

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0

I have two string lists which have same size.
I want to create a dictionary, the key is from `listA`, the value is from `listB`.

What is the fast way?

I used the code:

```
        List<string> ListA;
        List<string> ListB;
        Dictionary<string,string> dict = new Dictionary<string,string>();
        for(int i=0;i<ListA.Count;i++)
        {
              dict[key] = listA[i];
              dict[value]= listB[i];
        }
```

I don't like this way, can I use `ToDictionary` method?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Starting with .NET 4.0, you can do it using LINQ's [`Zip`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698.aspx) method, like this:

```
var res = ListA.Zip(ListB, (a,b) => new {a, b})
               .ToDictionary(p=>p.a, p=>p.b);
```

> [Zip] method merges each element of the first sequence with an element that has the same index in the second sequence.

Comment: Are you sure Zip ensures order?

Comment: While this answer is perfectly valid, I must add that I think this is somehow not a good idea if something that simple (creating a dictionary from two lists) requires the developer that reads the code to open the MSDN doc to check what's actually done.

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso There is absolutely nothing inherently inefficient about this implementation: it finishes in `O(N)`, does not perform unnecessary lookups, and accomplishes in one simple statement something that would otherwise require a loop. While it may be slower in theory, one would be hard-pressed to find a natural example where efficiency is so important as to warrant a rewrite of this statement as something more efficient. At any rate, rewriting for efficiency without profiling is a certain case of premature micro-optimization.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight in this case I would not use LINQ which does not help or improve the readability as it is something very easy to achieve with a classic loop (@ken2k answer).
If you test it (stopwatch) using big lists you will see performance difference(internally LINQ uses loops). Anyway the question is : what is the vantages of using LINQ in this case?

Comment: @MassimilianoPeluso To me, the advantage of using `Zip` is its slightly better readability. I fully understand, however, that my answer is biased, because I have been using LINQ nonstop for nearly five years; a great deal of C# practitioners out there would have an opposite take on the readability of these two approaches.

Answer (score 4):

You could create an anonymous type with the index which you can use to get the `B` at this index.

```
Dictionary<string, string> dict = ListA
    .Select((a, i) => new { A = a, Index = i })
    .ToDictionary(x => x.A, x => ListB.ElementAtOrDefault(x.Index));
```

Note that the value would be `null` in case `ListB` is smaller than `ListA`.

Answer (score 2):

I would not bother (if it is possible) as your version is readable, easy to debug and quicker than any other LINQ solutions (especially if you are working with big list).

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't change your version.

The following piece of code is more readable than LINQ stuff in your case, IMHO.

```
var ListA = new List<string>();
var ListB = new List<string>();
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

for (int i = 0; i < ListA.Count; i++)
{
    dict.Add(ListA[i], ListB[i]);
}
```